# In vb.net, how to display 4 hour increments on x axis on a chart graph

Tags: vb.net, charts

I would like the x axis to show 4 hour increments. So 5 for a 24 hour period.

I load my array with 180 date entries - 3 hours - 60 per hour.

8/29/2016 5:00:30 PM threw 8/29/2016 5:59:30 PM

8/29/2016 6:00:30 PM threw 8/29/2016 6:59:30 PM

8/29/2016 7:00:30 PM threw 8/29/2016 7:59:30 PM

This is what I get now:
[image]

Note: for above, the array type is String. If I make it Datetime, the points do not plot and the dates are odd.  As below.[image]

Here's my code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim iServerId As Integer = 47
    Dim strTimeframe As String = "day"

    Chart1.Series.Clear()
    Chart1.Titles.Add("Server id " & iServerId.ToString() & ", Port index 8. The In/Out Mbps - by " & strTimeframe)

    ' Rotates the X axis text.
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Angle = -90

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    ' I would the increment to show every 4 hours.
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 1
    ' When running 'day', this shows every 5 minutes: 5:00:30 PM, 5:05:30 PM, 5:10:30 PM, 5:15:30 PM, 5:20:30 PM increment lines.
    Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 24

    ' Arrays - 1 X array for the "start time", 2 Y arrays for the "IN Mbps" and "OUT Mbps".
    Dim xAxisArray() As String
    Dim yAxisInMbpsArray() As Integer
    Dim yAxisOutMbpsArray() As Integer        

    Dim DBFunc As New DatabaseFunctions
    Dim drReturn As SqlDataReader
    Dim strMessage As String = ""
    Dim iArrayCount As Integer = 0

    DBFunc.OpenDB()

    Try
        With DBFunc.objCmd
            .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            .CommandText = "SelectBandwidthLogCalculated"
            .Parameters.Clear()

            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServerId", iServerId)
            .Parameters.AddWithValue("@TimeFrame", strTimeframe)

            ' Execute.
            drReturn = .ExecuteReader

            If drReturn.HasRows = True Then
                ' Build the array.
                Do While drReturn.Read
                    ReDim Preserve xAxisArray(iArrayCount)
                    ReDim Preserve yAxisInMbpsArray(iArrayCount)
                    ReDim Preserve yAxisOutMbpsArray(iArrayCount)

                    xAxisArray(iArrayCount) = drReturn("StartDate")
                    yAxisInMbpsArray(iArrayCount) = drReturn("BandwidthInMbps")
                    yAxisOutMbpsArray(iArrayCount) = drReturn("BandwidthOutMbps")

                    ' increment.
                    iArrayCount += 1
                Loop

                ' Close reader.
                drReturn.Close()
            Else
                ' No rows error.
                strMessage = "Critical Error - no rows. Contact IT, do not continue."
            End If
        End With
    Catch sqlex As SqlException
        strMessage = "Critical Error - when retrieving rows. Contact IT, do not continue. SQL Error: " & sqlex.Message
    Catch ex As Exception
        strMessage = "Critical Error - when retrieving rows. Contact IT, do not continue. Error: " & ex.Message
    Finally
        ' Close database.
        DBFunc.CloseDB()
    End Try

    If strMessage = "" Then
        'Create a new series and add data points to it.
        Dim sIn As New Series
        Dim sOut As New Series

        sIn.Name = "In Mbps"
        sOut.Name = "Out Mbps"

        ' Change to a line graph.
        sIn.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line
        sOut.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line

        ' Since both arrays should have the same qty, either's count should be fine.
        For idx As Integer = 0 To xAxisArray.Count - 1
            sIn.Points.AddXY(xAxisArray(idx), yAxisInMbpsArray(idx))
            sOut.Points.AddXY(xAxisArray(idx), yAxisOutMbpsArray(idx))
        Next

        'Add the series to the Chart1 control.
        Chart1.Series.Add(sIn)
        Chart1.Series.Add(sOut)
    Else
        lblMessage.Text = strMessage
    End If
End Sub
```

After making suggested changes:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make it a `DateTime` and make sure you do

```
sIn.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time
sOut.XValueType = ChartValueType.Time
```

Then to make a 4 hour interval

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.IntervalType = DataVisualization.Charting.DateTimeIntervalType.Hours
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 4
```

Check on your previous assignments, to make sure they jive with the interval and type

```
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Minimum = 1
Chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Maximum = 24
```

Comment: A added those before the For clause. But i get AxisX is not a member of series.

Comment: Fixed, I confess I didn't test it before :)

Comment: No  good - chart does not plot the points and the dates are not 4 hours. They are numerous now (I will include in my original post a jpeg of how it looks now).  And I actually already had min and maxes already so I did not add them per the suggestion.